# Syntax of aggregateByKey in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below is the command:

```
orderItems.join(orders)
  .map(x =>((x.2.2.split(",")(1),x.1),x.2.1.split(",")(4).toFloat))
  .reduceByKey(+)
  .map(x => (x.1.1,x.2))
  .aggregateByKey((0,0.0))(
    (accu,value) => (accu.1 + 1 , accu.2 + value),
    (value1,value2) => (value1.1 + value2.1,value1.2 + value2.2))
```

In the above code if we provide `(0,0.0)` in place of `((0,0.0))` in `aggregateByKey` method its gives below error:

> :25: error: overloaded method value aggregateByKey with alternatives:
>   [U](zeroValue: U, numPartitions: Int)(seqOp: (U, Float) => U, combOp: (U, U) => U)(implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[U])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, U)] 
>   [U](zeroValue: U, partitioner: org.apache.spark.Partitioner)(seqOp: (U, Float) => U, combOp: (U, U) => U)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[U])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, U)]
>   cannot be applied to (Int, Double)

Anyone have any idea why we need to give two brackets (()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how signature looks like:

```
def aggregateByKey[U](zeroValue: U)(seqOp: (U, V) ⇒ U, combOp: (U, U) ⇒ U)
```

- `rdd.aggregateByKey((0, 0.0))(...)` is a function call with a single argument of type `Tuple2[Int, Double]`
- `rdd.aggregateByKey(0, 0.0)(...)` with two arguments of type `Int` and `Double` respectively. It doesn't match the signature.